# Civicrm report:Bar chart and Pie chart support for different modules

Tags: civireport

Does civicrm support bar & pie chart report for all modules?? and if not then can we do it with custom templates?

Comment: any idea on civisualize,will that help me for getting enhanced report (bar and pie chart diagrams)?

Comment: Thanks for your question.  You are more likely to get a useful reply if you provide more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to take a month over month analysis using civireport,but I see that only bar chart and pie chart diagrams  are  available in some of the default templates(eg:mailing,contribution).Is there any way that I can get pie and bar chart diagrams using event,contact reports?

Answer (score 3):

If it is problematic to do via civireport, drupal users can build charts off Views without needing to code. I have used both charts and charts_highcharts to easily provide charts based on a range of civi entities